# Dúvida com lógica para selecionar div

Tags: jquery, html5, css3

Estou com o seguinte problema, quando clico em uma div a mesma deverá ficar com o **background-color** preto e o **color** da cor que realmente é o background, até aí está funcionando normalmente, porém só quando clique em uma div apenas uma vez, no segundo clique a div que é clicada não perde o **opacity**, haveria algum modo de resolver isto:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.grade:eq(1)').on('click', () => {
     $('.grade:eq(1)').css({
        'background-color': '#000',
        'color': '#EC0080',
        'filter': 'opacity(1)' 
     }) 
     $('.grade:eq(0)').css({
        'background-color': '#009ADE',
        'color': '#FFF',
     'filter': 'opacity(0.4)'
     }).mouseenter(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(0)').css('filter','opacity(1)')
     }).mouseleave(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(0)').css('filter','opacity(0.4)')
     })
     $('.grade:eq(2)').css({
        'background-color': '#FFEA00',
        'color': '#FFF',
     'filter': 'opacity(0.4)'
     }).mouseenter(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(2)').css('filter','opacity(1)')
     }).mouseleave(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(2)').css('filter','opacity(0.4)')
     })
  })
  
  $('.grade:eq(2)').on('click', () => {
     $('.grade:eq(2)').css({
        'background-color': '#000',
        'color': '#FFEA00',
        'filter': 'opacity(1)'
     })
     $('.grade:eq(1)').css({
        'background-color': '#EC0080',
        'color': '#FFF',
     'filter': 'opacity(0.4)'
     }).mouseenter(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(1)').css('filter','opacity(1)')
     }).mouseleave(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(1)').css('filter','opacity(0.4)')
     })
     $('.grade:eq(0)').css({
        'background-color': '#009ADE',
        'color': '#FFF',
     'filter': 'opacity(0.4)'
     }).mouseenter(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(0)').css('filter','opacity(1)')
     }).mouseleave(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(0)').css('filter','opacity(0.4)')
     })
  })
  
  $('.grade:eq(0)').on('click', () => {
     $('.grade:eq(0)').css({
        'background-color': '#000',
        'color': '#009ADE',
        'filter': 'opacity(1)' 
     })
 $('.grade:eq(1)').css({
        'background-color': '#EC0080',
        'color': '#FFF',
        'filter': 'opacity(0.4)'
    }).mouseenter(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(1)').css('filter','opacity(1)')
    }).mouseleave(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(1)').css('filter','opacity(0.4)')
    })
    $('.grade:eq(2)').css({
        'background-color': '#FFEA00',
        'color': '#FFF',
        'filter': 'opacity(0.4)'
    }).mouseenter(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(2)').css('filter','opacity(1)')
    }).mouseleave(() => {
        $('.grade:eq(2)').css('filter','opacity(0.4)')
    })

  }) 
})
```

```css
.grades {
    width: 350px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: baseline;
}
.grade {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color: #009ADE;
    filter: opacity(0.4);
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background-color: #EC0080;
    filter: opacity(0.4);
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background-color: #FFEA00;
    filter: opacity(0.4);
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+1):hover {
    filter: opacity(1);
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+2):hover {
    filter: opacity(1);
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+3):hover {
    filter: opacity(1);
}
.grade:nth-last-child(2) {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #EC0080;
    filter: opacity(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grades">
   <div class="grade">21h</div>
   <div class="grade">22h</div>
   <div class="grade" id="escolhido">23h</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ola LeAndrade tudo certo?
Para fazer o trabalhado de selecionado achei melhor incluir uma classe ".escolhido" que contenha todo o css, então ao clicar em uma ".grade" removo todos as classes ".escolhido"

```
$('.grade').removeClass('escolhido')
```

Então eu incluo somente naquela grade clicada

```
$(this).addClass('escolhido')
```

Quando o problema que estava dando em seu código, o motivo era por conta dos eventos de **mouseenter** e **mouseleave**
espero ter ajudado

```js
$(function() {
  $('.grade').on('click', function() {
    $('.grade').removeClass('escolhido')
    $(this).addClass('escolhido')
  })
})
```

```css
.grades {
    width: 350px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: baseline;
}
.grade {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.grade:not(.escolhido) {
    filter: opacity(0.4);
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background-color: #009ADE;
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background-color: #EC0080;
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+3) {
    background-color: #FFEA00;
}
.grade:hover {
    filter: opacity(1);
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+1).escolhido {
    color: #009ADE;
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+2).escolhido {
    color: #EC0080;
}
.grade:nth-child(3n+3).escolhido {
    color: #FFEA00;
}
.grades .escolhido {
    background-color: #000;
    filter: opacity(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grades">
   <div class="grade">21h</div>
   <div class="grade">22h</div>
   <div class="grade escolhido">23h</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Thiago, obrigado por tentar ajudar, sua resposta me ajudou em parte, porém precisaria deixar a cor do texto com a cor do **background** e não somente rosa, mas, agradeço muito a ajuda!

Comment: Poxa LeAndrade verdade, acabei não me atentando nesse detalhe do texto em seu exemplo, já faz algum tempinho deve ter conseguido resolver, mas de qualquer forma fiz uns ajustes no CSS acredito que agora esta ok

Comment: Boa Thiago, obrigado pela ajuda, tinha meio que resolvido com js, mas, utilizarei da forma que fez com Css mesmo, valeu man!